# With jQuery, how can I .toggle() an element from a selected position to a final position and size?

Tags: jquery, function

I would like to let a user click a button, and have a DIV open from the center of that button and grow to fill most of the page. Here's a visual:

[image]

The final position and size I'm going for is this:

```
<style>
.pageframe {
    width: 95%;
    min-height: 96%;
    left: 2%;
    top: 2%;
}
</style>
```

I will also need to have the reverse happen: When the user clicks a "close" button, the DIV evenly shrinks back into the center of the button and disappears.

I suspect this is really simple, but I'm new to jQuery. Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at [animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/). Example in docs does similar thing to what you want

Comment: @charlietfl I read that yesterday and didn't get it. Just now, I read it 3 times and finally understand! Thanks! This is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look my example, and try tweak it abit.

**JS**

```
$( "#here" ).click(function() {
  $(".child" ).toggleClass( "sink" );
});
```

**CSS**

```
.parent{
  padding:5px;
  background:orange;
  height:100vh;
  position:relative;
}

#here {
  position:relative;
  z-index:1000;
}

.child{
  position:absolute;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  bottom:50%;
  right:50%;
  background:purple;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
  transform:translate(-50%,-50%) scale(0);
}

.sink{
  top:5px;
  left:5px;
  bottom:5px;
  right:5px;
  width: inherit;
  height: inherit;
  transform:translate(0%,0%) scale(1);
}
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/ox4syk90/)

Comment: Upvote - that definitely does the trick! I didn't see where the duration is set. Also, I'm looking for a way to do this so the motion is even. Your example is like a curve ball in the game of baseball. @charlietfl had left a comment suggesting I try .animate() so that's what I'm doing now.

Comment: The duration i set in css. as you can see the transition on the parent div were 0.5s ease-out.

Comment: Right! I messed with Animate() for a while, but I'm back to your example and I've been able to tweak it to work pretty great. I haven't implemented it in my project yet but I'm about to. Thanks!